# Inverse function of $f(r,\varphi)=\begin{pmatrix}r\cos(\varphi)\\r\sin(\varphi)\end{pmatrix}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry, inverse

> Let be $f:~\!]0,\infty[~\!\times~\![0,\pi]\to\mathbb{R}^2$, with $f(r,\varphi)=\begin{pmatrix}r\cos(\varphi)\\r\sin(\varphi)\end{pmatrix}$. Compute the inverse function.

---

**My approach:**

We know that $r^2\cos^2(\varphi)+r^2\sin^2(\varphi)=r^2$, therefor
$$
r^2=x^2+y^2\implies r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\text{ because } r>0.
$$
Further,
$$
\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cos(\varphi)=x \implies \varphi=\arccos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right).
$$
Hence, $g:\mathbb{R}^2\to~\!]0,\infty[~\!\times~\![0,\pi]$, with $g(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\\\arccos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)
\end{pmatrix}$ is the inverse function.

The problem is that $g$ is not injective so it can't be the inverse. But I don't see where I did a mistake?

Comment: You don't need $g$ to have domain $\mathbb{R}^2$; since the angle is restricted to $[0,\pi]$ you just need $(x,y)$ such that $y\geq 0$.

Comment: $f:(0,\infty)\times[0,\pi]\to \Bbb{R}^2$ is not a bijection. It is only injective, so we only have an inverse after restricting the target space of $f$ from $\Bbb{R}^2$ to its image (a very common thing to do). This yields an inverse $g:\text{image}(f)\to (0,\infty)\times [0,\pi]$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo, I have only performed "well defined manipualtions" to get the inverse so why doesn't produce it a bijective function? I mean there is no step that requires $y\geq 0$.

Comment: For $f$ to be invertible, you need it to be a bijection. It it clear immediately that your $f:(0,\infty)\times[0,\pi]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is not surjective. Indeed it should be pretty clear to see that $\operatorname{image}(f)=\left(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\right)\setminus\{(0,0)\}$, i.e. the upper half plane without the origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the functions $f:(0,\infty)\times[0,\pi]\to\Bbb{R}^2$ and $g:\Bbb{R}^2\to (0,\infty)\times [0,\pi]$ as you have defined them. The method of "letting $x=r\cos\phi$ and $y=r\sin\phi$ and solving such that $r>0, \phi\in [0,\pi]$" only proves that
\begin{align}
g\circ f=\text{id}_{(0,\infty)\times [0,\pi]}.
\end{align}
But this is of course not the definition of $g$ being the inverse function to $f$. For $g$ to be the inverse, we need the extra condition that $f\circ g=\text{id}_{\Bbb{R}^2}$. But this is not true (why not?)

So, what's the fix?

Let $H=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb{R}^2\,:\, (x,y)\neq (0,0), y\geq 0\}$. This is the closed upper half plane minus the origin. The function $f:(0,\infty)\times [0,\pi]\to\Bbb{R}^2$ has image equal to $H$. Now, consider the restricted target space function $\tilde{f}:(0,\infty)\times[0,\pi]\to H$, $\tilde{f}(r,\phi):=f(r,\phi)$. Next, consider the function $\tilde{g}:H\to (0,\infty)\times [0,\pi]$, $\tilde{g}(x,y)=g(x,y)$.

So, $\tilde{f}$ is obtained by restricting the target space of $f$, while $\tilde{g}$ is obtained by restricting the domain of $g$. It is still easily verified that $\tilde{g}\circ \tilde{f}=g\circ f=\text{id}_{(0,\infty)\times [0,\pi]}$. To check the condition for inverse, we need to look at the composition the other way around. So, let $(x,y)\in H$. The question is whether or not $(\tilde{f}\circ \tilde{g})(x,y)=(x,y)$. Well, since the rules of the functions are the same we have
\begin{align}
(\tilde{f}\circ \tilde{g})(x,y)&=(f\circ g)(x,y)\\
&=f(g(x,y))\\
&=f\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\arccos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)\right)\\
&=\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot \cos\left(\arccos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)\right),
\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot \sin\left(\arccos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)\right) \right)
\end{align}
Now, cosine of arccos simplifies nicely:
\begin{align}
\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot \cos\left(\arccos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)\right)&=
\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=x.
\end{align}
However, to simplify sine of arccos, we have to be more careful. Note that $\arccos:[-1,1]\to [0,\pi]$, also $\sin$ is non-negative on the interval $[0,\pi]$, so we have
\begin{align}
\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot \sin\left(\arccos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)\right)&=
\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot \sqrt{\sin^2\left(\arccos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)\right)}\\
&=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot \sqrt{1- \cos^2\left(\arccos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)\right)}\\
&=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)^2}\\
&=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}}\\
&=y.
\end{align}
It is this last step which uses the fact that $y\geq 0$, in the manipulation $\sqrt{y^2}=|y|=y$. Therefore, we can indeed deduce that $(\tilde{f}\circ\tilde{g})(x,y)=(x,y)$ and thus conclude that $\tilde{f}$ and $\tilde{g}$ are indeed inverse functions.

Usually, no one does this extra step of verifying $\tilde{f}\circ \tilde{g}=\text{id}_{H}$, because it is "obvious by picture".

So, you have to be careful with restricting things appropriately in order to get a correct inverse function. Note by the way, that it is common terminology to avoid introducing new notation in the form of tildes to denote the functions obtained by restriction; this is the sort of thing which one just says in words (or not at all:).